# Disavow tool property drop down menu has nothing in it even a month after verifying my site in Google Search Console

Tags: google, google-search-console, robots.txt, disavow-links

About a month ago, I launched a site and after launching, I installed the search console on it.

After a month, the disavow menu has not been activated yet (as you can see in picture)

[image]

and this is my `robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

I verified the Search Console via DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly don't need to use the disavow feature.   99% of websites don't need to use it.  It is for when you know that somebody else created spammy links to your website and you saw a manual action or ranking drop tied directly to the links.   Using disavow links on a healthy website can *cause* ranking drops or even pages from your site not to be indexed at all.

[Disavow backlinks - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en) says:

> **WARNING** -- This  is an advanced feature and should only be used with caution. If used incorrectly, this feature can potentially harm your site’s performance in Google’s search results.
>
> ...
>
> You should disavow backlinks only if:
>
> 1. You believe you have a considerable number of spammy, artificial, or low-quality links pointing to your site, and
> 2. The links have caused a manual action, or likely will cause a manual action, on your site.

The disavow links feature has not been migrated to the latest version of Google search engine console.  The new version of search engine console lets you add "domain properties" in addition to the old style "prefix properties" that were the only type available in the old search console.   Features in the old search console don't know how to use domain properties.

Since you verified your website as a domain property using the DNS verification mechanism, the disavow feature is not available to you.   If you need to use disavow links, you will need to add a prefix property for your website as well.   You don't need to delete the domain property.  You can have both a domain property and a prefix property verified for the same website.

Once you have added the prefix properties for all your sites, that empty drop down will contain a list of your web sites that have been verified as prefix properties.  I have a number of websites, some of which are verified by domain and some by prefix.  Only my prefix verified sites appear in that list.